# Remote file size without downloading file

Tags: php, curl

Is there a way to get the size of a remote file http://my_url/my_file.txt without downloading the file?

Comment: Leaving this as a comment, not an answer as I realize the questions is PHP not WordPress... but if you happen to be working in WP, try this: `wp_get_http_headers( $file )->offsetGet( 'content-length' )`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Found something about this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#92462):

> Here's the best way (that I've found) to get the size of a remote
>   file. Note that HEAD requests don't get the actual body of the request,
>   they just retrieve the headers. So making a HEAD request to a resource
>   that is 100MB will take the same amount of time as a HEAD request to a
>   resource that is 1KB.

```
<?php
/**
 * Returns the size of a file without downloading it, or -1 if the file
 * size could not be determined.
 *
 * @param $url - The location of the remote file to download. Cannot
 * be null or empty.
 *
 * @return The size of the file referenced by $url, or -1 if the size
 * could not be determined.
 */
function curl_get_file_size( $url ) {
  // Assume failure.
  $result = -1;

  $curl = curl_init( $url );

  // Issue a HEAD request and follow any redirects.
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, get_user_agent_string() );

  $data = curl_exec( $curl );
  curl_close( $curl );

  if( $data ) {
    $content_length = "unknown";
    $status = "unknown";

    if( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $status = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    if( preg_match( "/Content-Length: (\d+)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
    if( $status == 200 || ($status > 300 && $status <= 308) ) {
      $result = $content_length;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
$file_size = curl_get_file_size( "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file" );
```

Comment: i was reading that earlier, wasn't sure if content-length meant the length or file size

Comment: well if the request returns a file, the request size *is* the file size

Comment: But keep in mind that there _can_ be responses without Content-length.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `curl_getinfo`, like @macki suggests?

Comment: i allways get 'unknown' as response?!

Comment: @Svish, yes, because that approach actually works. The approach presented here fails on redirected URLs, since it grabs the first Content-Length which is not (necessarily?) the *final* Content-Length. In my experience.

Comment: This did not work for me as `get_user_agent_string()` was not defined. Removing the entire line made the whole thing work.

Comment: this fails when tested with: `http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhainaut/` see SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761377/prevent-loading-from-remote-source-if-file-is-larger-than-a-given-size

Comment: This answer omits CURL_TIMEOUT. It is possible for the target server to exploit this. As a sidenote to anyone using the above function, if $url is provided by user input, make sure that it is a valid URL before passing it to cURL.

Comment: if the server does not support HEAD ,it will return 405

Comment: Like @Rapti I got an error message for `get_user_agent_string()` which was likely a local function left out of code. It works when line commented out, but maybe instead of function use`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: After disabling selinux this worked, but only wthj image and PDF. It doesn't give a result for mp4.

Comment: after  `$data = curl_exec( $curl );` use `$info = curl_getinfo($curl);` and gather `$result = $info['download_content_length'];`  simple !

Comment: `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` does not require the presence of `Content-Length` so in this scenario, this will fail

Answer (score 69):

Try this code

```
function retrieve_remote_file_size($url){
     $ch = curl_init($url);

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

     curl_close($ch);
     return $size;
}
```

Comment: If this doesn’t work for you, you might want to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me for an image. I do have `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to true.

Comment: @Abenil add this parameter.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Comment: @Davinder Kumar: thanks so much, adding your code make the above code works.

Comment: Your Welcome! @TrungLeNguyenNhat

Comment: What does `ch` stand for? Channel?

Comment: Works like a charm for me, to retrieve image and video sizes from the Google Photos API, using the file `baseUrl` as the parameter for this function.  (Function shared to answer a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57906465/8112776).)

Comment: @Gherman - I'd assume `ch` is short for "[curl handle](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-init.php#refsect1-function.curl-init-returnvalues)" but there's no reason you couldn't use a different variable name in the 7 places it is used in this function.

Answer (score 32):

As mentioned a couple of times, the way to go is to retrieve the information *from the response header's `Content-Length` field*.

However, you should note that

- the server you're probing not necessarily implements the HEAD method(!)
- there's absolutely no need to manually craft a HEAD request (which, again, might not even be supported) using `fopen` or alike or even to invoke the curl library, when PHP has [`get_headers()`](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) (remember: [K.I.S.S.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle))

Use of [`get_headers()`](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) follows the [K.I.S.S. principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) **and** works even if the server you're probing does not support the HEAD request.

So, here's my version (gimmick: returns human-readable formatted size ;-)):

Gist: https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/f26300ffd7e50a92bc4d (curl and get_headers version)
get_headers()-Version:

```
<?php     
/**
 *  Get the file size of any remote resource (using get_headers()), 
 *  either in bytes or - default - as human-readable formatted string.
 *
 *  @author  Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 *  @license MIT <http://eyecatchup.mit-license.org/>
 *  @url     <https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/f26300ffd7e50a92bc4d>
 *
 *  @param   string   $url          Takes the remote object's URL.
 *  @param   boolean  $formatSize   Whether to return size in bytes or formatted.
 *  @param   boolean  $useHead      Whether to use HEAD requests. If false, uses GET.
 *  @return  string                 Returns human-readable formatted size
 *                                  or size in bytes (default: formatted).
 */
function getRemoteFilesize($url, $formatSize = true, $useHead = true)
{
    if (false !== $useHead) {
        stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => 'HEAD')));
    }
    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, 1));
    // content-length of download (in bytes), read from Content-Length: field
    $clen = isset($head['content-length']) ? $head['content-length'] : 0;

    // cannot retrieve file size, return "-1"
    if (!$clen) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!$formatSize) {
        return $clen; // return size in bytes
    }

    $size = $clen;
    switch ($clen) {
        case $clen < 1024:
            $size = $clen .' B'; break;
        case $clen < 1048576:
            $size = round($clen / 1024, 2) .' KiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1073741824:
            $size = round($clen / 1048576, 2) . ' MiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1099511627776:
            $size = round($clen / 1073741824, 2) . ' GiB'; break;
    }

    return $size; // return formatted size
}
```

Usage:

```
$url = 'http://download.tuxfamily.org/notepadplus/6.6.9/npp.6.6.9.Installer.exe';
echo getRemoteFilesize($url); // echoes "7.51 MiB"
```

---

**Additional note:** The Content-Length header is optional. Thus, as a general solution **it isn't bullet proof**!

---

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. True, `Content-Length` is optional, but it's the only way to get the file size without downloading it - and `get_headers` is the best way to get `content-length`.

Comment: Be aware that this will change the preference for the request method to HEAD inside all subsequent HTTP requests for this PHP process. Use `stream_context_create` to create a separate context to use for the call to `get_headers` (7.1+).

Comment: just adding, that if your URL or DOCUMENT file name has spaces in it, this will return a -1

Answer (score 22):

Php function `get_headers()` works for me to check the **content-length** as

```
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com/image.jpg', 1);
$filesize = $headers['Content-Length'];
```

For More Detail : [**PHP Function get_headers()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Comment: For me (with nginx) the header was Content-Length

Answer (score 15):

Sure. Make a headers-only request and look for the `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 9):

one line best solution :

```
echo array_change_key_case(get_headers("http://.../file.txt",1))['content-length'];
```

php is too delicius

```
function urlsize($url):int{
   return array_change_key_case(get_headers($url,1))['content-length'];
}

echo urlsize("http://.../file.txt");
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure, but couldn't you use the get_headers function for this?

```
$url     = 'http://example.com/dir/file.txt';
$headers = get_headers($url, true);

if ( isset($headers['Content-Length']) ) {
   $size = 'file size:' . $headers['Content-Length'];
}
else {
   $size = 'file size: unknown';
}

echo $size;
```

Comment: With this example, it is possible for the target server at $url to exploit get_headers into keeping the connection open until the PHP process times out (by returning the headers very slowly, while not slowly enough to let the connection go stale). Since total PHP processes might be limited by FPM, this can allow a type of slow loris attack when multiple 
"users" access your get_headers script simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and most efficient implementation:

```
function remote_filesize($url, $fallback_to_download = false)
{
    static $regex = '/^Content-Length: *+\K\d++$/im';
    if (!$fp = @fopen($url, 'rb')) {
        return false;
    }
    if (isset($http_response_header) && preg_match($regex, implode("\n", $http_response_header), $matches)) {
        return (int)$matches[0];
    }
    if (!$fallback_to_download) {
        return false;
    }
    return strlen(stream_get_contents($fp));
}
```

Comment: OP indicated "without downloading the file."

This method loads the file into memory from the remote server (eg: downloading). Even with fast connections between servers, this can easily time out or take way too long on large files.

Note: You never closed $fp which is not in global scope

Comment: This function DOES NOT download body as long as possible; if it contains `Content-Length` header. And explicit `$fp` closing is NOT NECESSARY; it is automatically released on expire. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: You can easily confirm the above using `nc -l localhost 8080`

Comment: Actually the most of `*close` functions are not necessary in modern PHP. They are from two historical reasons: implementation restriction and 
mimicking the C language.

Comment: Headers are unreliable and fallback download goes against OP. Finally, if you open a file, simply close it. Garbage collectors are no excuse for lazy developers saving a single line of code.

Comment: Your opinion about GC is proper when variable scope is unclear from its context. In this example, however, the  scope is definitely enclosed and it MUST be automatically, instantly released. So your business have no means other than keeping your strict coding rule.

Comment: BTW, the modern OOP-style stream interface `SplFileObject` has no method for closing internal resource handle. Procedural closing is inconsistent with modern interface at least about streamings.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is already tagged "php" and "curl", I'm assuming you know how to use Curl in PHP.

If you set `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE)` then you will make a HEAD request and can probably check the "Content-Length" header of the response, which will be only headers.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below function to get Remote file size

```
function remote_file_size($url){
    $head = "";
    $url_p = parse_url($url);

    $host = $url_p["host"];
    if(!preg_match("/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/",$host)){

        $ip=gethostbyname($host);
        if(!preg_match("/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/",$ip)){

            return -1;
        }
    }
    if(isset($url_p["port"]))
    $port = intval($url_p["port"]);
    else
    $port    =    80;

    if(!$port) $port=80;
    $path = $url_p["path"];

    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 20);
    if(!$fp) {
        return false;
        } else {
        fputs($fp, "HEAD "  . $url  . " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "HOST: " . $host . "\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "User-Agent: http://www.example.com/my_application\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        $headers = "";
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $headers .= fgets ($fp, 128);
            }
        }
    fclose ($fp);

    $return = -2;
    $arr_headers = explode("\n", $headers);
    foreach($arr_headers as $header) {

        $s1 = "HTTP/1.1";
        $s2 = "Content-Length: ";
        $s3 = "Location: ";

        if(substr(strtolower ($header), 0, strlen($s1)) == strtolower($s1)) $status = substr($header, strlen($s1));
        if(substr(strtolower ($header), 0, strlen($s2)) == strtolower($s2)) $size   = substr($header, strlen($s2));
        if(substr(strtolower ($header), 0, strlen($s3)) == strtolower($s3)) $newurl = substr($header, strlen($s3));  
    }

    if(intval($size) > 0) {
        $return=intval($size);
    } else {
        $return=$status;
    }

    if (intval($status)==302 && strlen($newurl) > 0) {

        $return = remote_file_size($newurl);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me on Ubuntu Linux apache server. I did have to init $size and $status at beginning of function, otherwise worked as is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that will work with servers that do not support `HEAD` requests.

It uses cURL to make a request for the content with an HTTP range header asking for the first byte of the file.

If the server supports range requests (most media servers will) then it will receive the response with the size of the resource.

If the server does not response with a byte range, it will look for a content-length header to determine the length.

If the size is found in a range or content-length header, the transfer is aborted.  If the size is not found and the function starts reading the response body, the transfer is aborted.

This could be a supplementary approach if a `HEAD` request results in a `405` method not supported response.

```
/**
 * Try to determine the size of a remote file by making an HTTP request for
 * a byte range, or look for the content-length header in the response.
 * The function aborts the transfer as soon as the size is found, or if no
 * length headers are returned, it aborts the transfer.
 *
 * @return int|null null if size could not be determined, or length of content
 */
function getRemoteFileSize($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    $headers = array(
        'Range: bytes=0-1',
        'Connection: close',
    );

    $in_headers = true;
    $size       = null;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2450.0 Iron/46.0.2450.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); // set to 1 to debug
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'r'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, $line) use (&$in_headers, &$size) {
        $length = strlen($line);

        if (trim($line) == '') {
            $in_headers = false;
        }

        list($header, $content) = explode(':', $line, 2);
        $header = strtolower(trim($header));

        if ($header == 'content-range') {
            // found a content-range header
            list($rng, $s) = explode('/', $content, 2);
            $size = (int)$s;
            return 0; // aborts transfer
        } else if ($header == 'content-length' && 206 != curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
            // found content-length header and this is not a 206 Partial Content response (range response)
            $size = (int)$content;
            return 0;
        } else {
            // continue
            return $length;
        }
    });

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($curl, $data) use ($in_headers) {
        if (!$in_headers) {
            // shouldn't be here unless we couldn't determine file size
            // abort transfer
            return 0;
        }

        // write function is also called when reading headers
        return strlen($data);
    });

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info   = curl_getinfo($ch);

    return $size;
}
```

Usage:

```
$size = getRemoteFileSize('http://example.com/video.mp4');
if ($size === null) {
    echo "Could not determine file size from headers.";
} else {
    echo "File size is {$size} bytes.";
}
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me. Always returns the answer. Even if `Content-Length` is not available.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking and commenting. I'm really glad you found it helpful!

Comment: This worked for me after I disabled selinux. Tested on remote image, PDF and mp4. mp4 gives a result but "22" is not the correct file size.

Answer (score 2):

If you using laravel 7 <=

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

Http::head($url)->header('Content-Length');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most answers here uses either CURL or are basing on reading headers. But in some certain situations you can use a way easier solution. Consider note on [`filesize()`'s docs on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php). You'll find there  a tip saying: "*As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) to determine which wrappers support stat() family of functionality*".

So, if your server and PHP parser is properly configured, you can simply use `filesize()` function, fed it with full URL, pointing to a remote file, which size you want to get, and let PHP do the all magic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I use it and got good result.

```
    function getRemoteFilesize($url)
{
    $file_headers = @get_headers($url, 1);
    if($size =getSize($file_headers)){
return $size;
    } elseif($file_headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 302 Found"){
        if (isset($file_headers["Location"])) {
            $url = $file_headers["Location"][0];
            if (strpos($url, "/_as/") !== false) {
                $url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "/_as/"));
            }
            $file_headers = @get_headers($url, 1);
            return getSize($file_headers);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function getSize($file_headers){

    if (!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" || $file_headers[0] == "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found") {
        return false;
    } elseif ($file_headers[0] == "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" || $file_headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") {

        $clen=(isset($file_headers['Content-Length']))?$file_headers['Content-Length']:false;
        $size = $clen;
        if($clen) {
            switch ($clen) {
                case $clen < 1024:
                    $size = $clen . ' B';
                    break;
                case $clen < 1048576:
                    $size = round($clen / 1024, 2) . ' KiB';
                    break;
                case $clen < 1073741824:
                    $size = round($clen / 1048576, 2) . ' MiB';
                    break;
                case $clen < 1099511627776:
                    $size = round($clen / 1073741824, 2) . ' GiB';
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $size;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, test like these:

```
echo getRemoteFilesize('http://mandasoy.com/wp-content/themes/spacious/images/plain.png').PHP_EOL;
echo getRemoteFilesize('http://bookfi.net/dl/201893/e96818').PHP_EOL;
echo getRemoteFilesize('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679268/downloading-files-as-attachment-filesize-incorrect').PHP_EOL;
```

Results:

24.82 KiB

912 KiB

101.85 KiB

Answer (score 1):

To cover the HTTP/2 request, the function provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602624/2380767 needs to be changed a bit:

```
<?php
/**
 * Returns the size of a file without downloading it, or -1 if the file
 * size could not be determined.
 *
 * @param $url - The location of the remote file to download. Cannot
 * be null or empty.
 *
 * @return The size of the file referenced by $url, or -1 if the size
 * could not be determined.
 */
function curl_get_file_size( $url ) {
  // Assume failure.
  $result = -1;

  $curl = curl_init( $url );

  // Issue a HEAD request and follow any redirects.
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, get_user_agent_string() );

  $data = curl_exec( $curl );
  curl_close( $curl );

  if( $data ) {
    $content_length = "unknown";
    $status = "unknown";

    if( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $status = (int)$matches[1];
    } elseif( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/2 (\d\d\d)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $status = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    if( preg_match( "/Content-Length: (\d+)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
    } elseif( preg_match( "/content-length: (\d+)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
        $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
    if( $status == 200 || ($status > 300 && $status <= 308) ) {
      $result = $content_length;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
?>
```