# how to determine file size before fetch using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I am providing a facility to my web users that they can upload their profile image from a url rather than uploading it from computer. I see here a mischievous user can provide url of a huge file or may be some url which is tailed to `/dev/random`, very unlikely but can happen. Is there a way I can determine the size of file before fetching it completely to my server?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file

Comment: @Topener: that topic wouldn't help OP to solve the **original** issue. *Sometimes* it's worth to read the *whole question*.

Comment: @Topener I could never have figured out what I should use to I search.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing to grab that remote file, there are different things you can do.

- While `file_get_contents('http://foobar.com')` is quite convenient, it gives you the least amount of control. I don't see how you could do a HEAD request to grab the `Content-Length` header up front.
- `fsockopen()` will make you cry when dealing with HTTPS.
- curl is, well, curl. It's just as ugly as powerful. There are other options, like the HTTP Pecl (basically wrapping curl) as well.

  1. check if the resource provides a Content-Length header. Do a HEAD request for this. Some servers/services don't handle HEAD requests. You'd then make a GET request and abort the transfer after you got the response headers.
  2. If (1) yielded a result, check if it's greater than you limit. If so, abort.
  3. Use curl to fetch the resource. Have a look at `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` to be able to abort the download if the volume exceeds your limit. You should also check this, if (1) yielded a result, as this result might've been spoofed.

In the very worst case you'll have made 1 HEAD and 1 GET request to acquire the Content-Length, as well as another GET request to download $yourLimit bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the [`Content-Length`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses) header in the response from the server.

Comment: What if there is no such header in the response?

Comment: What if they supplied `Content-Length: 123` but actually sent (a whole lot) more than that?