# PHP check file size in via Internet

Tags: php

How to check file size in via Internet? The sample below is my code that does not work

```
echo filesize('http://localhost/wordpress-3.1.2.zip');
echo filesize('http://www.wordpress.com/wordpress-3.1.2.zip');
```

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file

Comment: You can check the `Content-Length` header, although it isn't guaranteed to be accurate. Most stable way is to download the file to the server in a temp location, then run `filesize()` on it.

Answer (score 3):

The filesize function is used to get size of files stored locally.* For remote files you must find other solution, for example:

```
<?php
function getSizeFile($url) {
    if (substr($url,0,4)=='http') {
        $x = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, 1),CASE_LOWER);
        if ( strcasecmp($x[0], 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') != 0 ) { $x = $x['content-length'][1]; }
        else { $x = $x['content-length']; }
    }
    else { $x = @filesize($url); }

    return $x;
}
?>
```

Source: See the first post-comment in link below

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

*Well, to be honest since PHP 5 there are some wrappers for file functions, see here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

You can find a lot more examples, even here on SO, this should satisfy your needs: [PHP: Remote file size without downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)

**Try to use search function before asking question next time!**

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
<?php
    function remotefsize($url) {
        $sch = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
        if (($sch != "http") && ($sch != "https") && ($sch != "ftp") && ($sch != "ftps")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (($sch == "http") || ($sch == "https")) {
            $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
            if ((!array_key_exists("Content-Length", $headers))) { return false; }
            return $headers["Content-Length"];
        }
        if (($sch == "ftp") || ($sch == "ftps")) {
            $server = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
            $port = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT);
            $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
            $user = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER);
            $pass = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS);
            if ((!$server) || (!$path)) { return false; }
            if (!$port) { $port = 21; }
            if (!$user) { $user = "anonymous"; }
            if (!$pass) { $pass = "phpos@"; }
            switch ($sch) {
                case "ftp":
                    $ftpid = ftp_connect($server, $port);
                    break;
                case "ftps":
                    $ftpid = ftp_ssl_connect($server, $port);
                    break;
            }
            if (!$ftpid) { return false; }
            $login = ftp_login($ftpid, $user, $pass);
            if (!$login) { return false; }
            $ftpsize = ftp_size($ftpid, $path);
            ftp_close($ftpid);
            if ($ftpsize == -1) { return false; }
            return $ftpsize;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that's probably not possible. The best way is to download the file via `file_get_contents` and then use `filesize` over the file. You can later delete the file too!