# Find file size of a remote file without downloading it

Tags: php

Follow up on the answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602624/37759

This solution works for image or pdfs, however, when I try it with text or javascript files `curl_exec` return `false`. Why?

For example getting file size of jquery file https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery/master/src/ajax.js

Comment: It works for me and I'm getting `21705` as the output. Is this different for you?

Comment: Yes `curl_exec` returns `false`. You tried with url  https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery/master/src/ajax.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has to do with GitHub  URL being `https`. You can tell cURL go ignore the certificate check, by doing:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

If this doesn't solve the issue, you can add a `echo curl_error($curl)` before `curl_close( $curl );` -- it might help you with debugging.

Comment: `curl_error($curl)` after the `curl_exec()` yields "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" here, confirming https being the root of the problem.