# Use php filesize function with GET variables

Tags: php, file

I am trying to use the filesize php function to automatically write the filesize in a meta tag I am using.

What I am doing normally is for example

```
<meta name="DC.format" content="<?= filesize($filename); ?> bytes">
```

Now, if this is used with the following syntax it returns:

```
php
<meta name="DC.format" content="<?= filesize("index.php"); ?> bytes">

resulting html
<meta name="DC.format" content="6412 bytes">
```

But if I use the following syntax I get the following error.

```
php
<meta name="DC.format" content="<?= filesize("index.php?locale=en_US"); ?> bytes">

resulting html
<meta name="DC.format" content="<br /><b>Warning</b>:  filesize():
stat failed for index.php?es=./&amp;en=./en/&amp;locale=en_US in
<b>D:\xampp\htdocs\casasenmeridabaspul.com-v2\header.php</b>
on line <b>87</b><br /> bytes">
```

What I suppose is happening is that filesize is getting the filesize of the specific file without doing any php processing or such. How can I calculate the resulting file size after all the server side has processed everything?

With a little more detail:

I have header.php, footer.php and index.php where index.php has the previous 2 included. I was thinking perhaps something like curl but I am not really familiar with it so I would leave it to the experts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a file.  It's text output from the execution of the file.  The best you can do is `strlen()` or `mb_strlen()` without using HTTP functions / classes I think:

```
<?= strlen(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/index.php?locale=en_US")); ?>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will use a HTTP request.

Comment: @ComFreek: Yes, they are passing a query string.

Comment: I think I'm having a cycle issue. As index.php includes header.php and the function is in header.php, when I am asking to calculate the filesize it goes to header again thus repeating the function and never calculating anything.

I was thinking perhaps adding an extra $_GET parameter and identifying it. What do you think?

Comment: I did it as I mentioned:


`<? if(!$_GET["calc"]) { echo strlen(file_get_contents("http://www.site.com/".$filename."?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]."&calc=1")); } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You pass an (invalid) local path to `filesize()` and it therefore tries to resolve it on your hard disk. This obviously fails due to the query parameters which invalidate the file name.

It is a valid part of a URI however. You can therefore start a HTTP request and get the size of the returned content:

[PHP: Remote file size without downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)

Please bear in mind that this method will fire off a HTTP request which can influence the performance quite a bit.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate it without the HTTP request?

Comment: This one seems more complex than the next one, why would  you recommend it?

Comment: @mihail_ov Well, since these are your PHP files and contain your logic, you could calculate the size (fire off an internal request; 'simulate' a request from an extern source internally). I recommend against AbraCadaver's solution because it will always download the file! This has a serious performance impact. The answer in the link I provided only executes a 'HEAD' requests which only returns some metadata.