# get_headers takes too much time for checking size of image

Tags: php, get-headers

hi i am using below code to check the size of remote image .it works but it takes lot of time to check the size of image is there any bette rway to do

```
<?php
  $url='http://testfile.com/test/sddkssk.jpg';
  $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, TRUE));
  $filesize = $head['content-length'];
  if ($filesize >= 131000) {     
    echo 'good image';
  }
```

but it takes 2-3 minute for each time to load is there any better way which can do same work very fast

Comment: How large is the image? Is it possible that the remote server doesn't understand the request for only the headers? Is it faster when you make the request in your browser?

Comment: @Pekka웃 this script is very slow from browsers also but all images loads fast when we directly paste the imaage url in browser

Comment: Profile your code and see *exactly* where the bottleneck is. Are you sure it's with `get_headers`?

Comment: If it's very slow in the browser as well, then it's likely an issue with the remote server? There may be nothing you can do.

Comment: Related [Remote file size without downloading file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2602612/1607098)

Comment: Are the server where you are running the script and the browser you are using on the same internet connection? Also, images may appear to load fast if they are cached, use a "private window" or something similar to see how fast they really load.

Comment: @Pekka웃  pleas ehelp it is taking years to load

Comment: If it's a problem with the remote server, there may not be anything you can do. Do you have to do this often? Are you using some form of caching?

Comment: @Pekka웃 is there any improvement can be done in my codes?

Comment: Regarding the speed? Not really. As said, the problem seems to be not caused by your code, but by the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$size = getimagesize("http://www.example.com/gifs/logo.gif");

// if the file name has space in it, encode it properly
$size = getimagesize("http://www.example.com/gifs/lo%20go.gif");
```

Comment: yes it is mixed type of files space is thr in few and in few it is not there. can u plz explain how to do this in my code

Comment: This will load the entire file first. It's not going to help the OP who is experiencing problems even when loading *just the headers*