# issue with filesize content-length

Tags: php

i am using below code to check the size of remote image and based on output it shows ok or not ok . but in one case where pinterest.com is there as url it gives wrong output.

for $op9 if link is other than pinterest it gives correct output but in pinterest it gives wrong output and one more thing i have noticed however the link is ending with .jpg in pinterest but it will not display any image instead it will ask for facebook login any idea how can i solve this issue

**CODE:**

```
<?php

$op9 = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.glamsham.com/download/wallpaper/22705/emraan-hashmi-wallpapers/47567.htm&media=http://media.glamsham.com/download/wallpaper/celebrities/images/e/emraan-hashmi-wallpaper-40-12x9.jpg';

//$op9 = 'http://photos1.meetupstatic.com/photos/member/9/3/6/e/member_87697742.jpeg';

$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($op9, TRUE));
$filesize = $head['content-length'];

if ($filesize >= 31000) {
    echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

Comment: Uhm .. why not use the file itself? Why do you need pinterest ? Like: `http://media.glamsham.com/download/wallpaper/celebrities/images/e/emraan-hashmi-wallpaper-40-12x9.jpg`, you can get it like: `parse_str($op9, $str); $img = $str['media'];`

Comment: @MihaiIorga i dont have control on link so i have to fetch it but i want to ignore images which are not really image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In first case:**

```
$op9 = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.glamsham.com/download/wallpaper/22705/emraan-hashmi-wallpapers/47567.htm&media=http://media.glamsham.com/download/wallpaper/celebrities/images/e/emraan-hashmi-wallpaper-40-12x9.jpg';
```

$filesize = $head['content-length'] **will be  an array**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '178' (length=3)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => string '0' (length=1)
```

and you compare it with ">=31000" and you will have "ok"

**In second case:**

```
$op9 = 'http://photos1.meetupstatic.com/photos/member/9/3/6/e/member_87697742.jpeg';
```

$filesize = $head['content-length']   **will be a  string** '57412' (length=5)

That's why if you compare  $filesize with ">=31000" you will not have "ok"

**Eited. Use strlen to get size:**

```
$op9 = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.glamsham.com/download/wallpaper/22705/emraan-hashmi-wallpapers/47567.htm&media=http://media.glamsham.com/download/wallpaper/celebrities/images/e/emraan-hashmi-wallpaper-40-12x9.jpg';

//$op9 = 'http://photos1.meetupstatic.com/photos/member/9/3/6/e/member_87697742.jpeg';

$filesize = strlen(file_get_contents($op9));
echo $filesize;  //here you will see the size
if ($filesize >= 31000) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

If you does not want to download the file use next:

Found something about this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#92462) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file):

> Here's the best way (that I've found) to get the size of a remote
>   file. Note that HEAD requests don't get the actual body of the request,
>   they just retrieve the headers. So making a HEAD request to a resource
>   that is 100MB will take the same amount of time as a HEAD request to a
>   resource that is 1KB.

```
<?php
/**
 * Returns the size of a file without downloading it, or -1 if the file
 * size could not be determined.
 *
 * @param $url - The location of the remote file to download. Cannot
 * be null or empty.
 *
 * @return The size of the file referenced by $url, or -1 if the size
 * could not be determined.
 */
function curl_get_file_size( $url ) {
  // Assume failure.
  $result = -1;

  $curl = curl_init( $url );

  // Issue a HEAD request and follow any redirects.
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, get_user_agent_string() );

  $data = curl_exec( $curl );
  curl_close( $curl );

  if( $data ) {
    $content_length = "unknown";
    $status = "unknown";

    if( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $status = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    if( preg_match( "/Content-Length: (\d+)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
    if( $status == 200 || ($status > 300 && $status <= 308) ) {
      $result = $content_length;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
$file_size = curl_get_file_size( "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file" );
```

Comment: why it will be ok in first case it should be false in first case and output should be nothing as it is not greater than 31000

Comment: Because when you compare array with integer , array will be always bigger.

Comment: what is the solution of this as i want these cases to be false as that is not a real image

Comment: Edited. Now you can use as I wrote. Hope it will help.

Comment: strlen will download complete image and it will be too slow

Comment: Edited again. I think you asked this.