# How to check file size before opening?

Tags: r, download, unzip, filesize

How can I check the size of a file before I load it into R?

For example:

http://math.ucdenver.edu/RTutorial/titanic.txt

I'd like to use the optimal command to open a file based on the file's size.

Comment: `?file.info` is probably what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921593/how-to-determine-the-file-size-of-a-remote-download-without-reading-the-entire-f is probably what you want

Comment: the accepted answer is not the most up-to-date answer

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `file.info()`

```
file.info("data/ullyses.txt")

                    size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime  uid  gid
data/ullyses.txt 1573151 FALSE  664 2015-06-01 15:25:55 2015-06-01 15:25:55 2015-06-01 15:25:55 1008 1008
```

Then extract the column called `size`:

```
file.info("data/ullyses.txt")$size
[1] 1573151
```

Comment: and if its from "http:" is there a way to measure size before loading?

Comment: You may have to use `download.file()` and then check the file size locally.

Comment: Since R 3.2 there's a `file.size()` wrapper.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps it has been added since this discussion, but at least for R3.4+, the answer is `file.size`.

Answer (score 8):

```
library(RCurl)
url = "http://math.ucdenver.edu/RTutorial/titanic.txt"
xx = getURL(url, nobody=1L, header=1L)
strsplit(xx, "\r\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides `file.size` mentioned above, you can also use `file_size` from package `fs`, which will print the size in a more human-readable output, showing MB or GB instead of bytes.

As an example, compare the output returned by the two functions:

```r
library(fs)

file.size(system.file("data/Rdata.rdb", package = "datasets"))
#> [1] 114974
fs::file_size(system.file("data/Rdata.rdb", package = "datasets"))
#> 112K

file.size(system.file("data/Rdata.rdb", package = "spData"))
#> [1] 2676333
fs::file_size(system.file("data/Rdata.rdb", package = "spData"))
#> 2.55M
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to download the file before knowing its size, you can try something like this:

*Note: This will only work in Mac or Linux.*

```
file_url = 'http://math.ucdenver.edu/RTutorial/titanic.txt'
curl_cmd = paste('curl -X HEAD -i', file_url)
system_cmd = paste(curl_cmd, '|grep Content-Length |cut -d : -f 2')
```

The above will pack together a string to be executed using `system()`. The `curl_cmd` string tells curl to go get just the header of the file.

The `system_cmd` string packs on some extra commands to parse the header and extract just the filesize.

Now, call `system()` and use the `intern = TRUE` argument to tell R to hold onto the output.

```
b <- system(system_cmd, intern = TRUE)
##  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current 
##                              Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
##   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0   
## curl: (18) transfer closed
```

It will download just the header for the file and parse it to get the filesize. Now `b` will be the filesize in bytes.

---

Then you can decide how to open the file, or print something friendly like:

```
print(paste("There are", as.numeric(b)/1e6, "mb in the file:", file_url))
## [1] "There are 0.055692 mb in the file: http://math.ucdenver.edu/RTutorial/titanic.txt"
```

Comment: It would be cool if someone could share a solution that works in all host environments. I tried fiddling in `RCurl` for about five minutes but didn't get very far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921593/how-to-determine-the-file-size-of-a-remote-download-without-reading-the-entire-f

Comment: Awesome! So much better.