# How to determine online file size before download in R?

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

The question is simple and there are similar questions in other languages, but not in R, as far as I could search.

I want to download a file in R code, but before downloading, I want to print out the size and estimation of the download time.
Is there any way to do this directly in base R, or using curl utilities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check file size before opening in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580798/how-to-check-file-size-before-opening-in-r)

Comment: The accepted answer does not. But there is another answer that helps. But the answer provided here is better at answering the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```r
download_size <- function(url) as.numeric(httr::HEAD(url)$headers$`content-length`)
```

Which would allow

```r
download_size("https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.pdf")
#> [1] 452557
```