# Is there a way to get the remote file size of a list of links?

Tags: php, file, curl, size

Is it possible to get the remote file size for a list of links, get the file size for each and every one of these links from a array or .txt file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file Might help you out right here.

Comment: Nope, thanks. I am looking at getting the remote file size of a list of links from an array.

Answer (score 1):

hope that below will fit your needs

```
function remote_file_size($url){

$header = get_headers($url, true);

if (isset($header['Content-Length']))

    return (int) $header['Content-Length'];
}
```

Comment: Nope, this isn't doing the trick. I want to get the file size for each link from an array. Say the array has a 100 links, i'd like to get the size of the 100 links each separately.

Comment: you call the function in a loop, i didnt get it. why its not working

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: while you are reading the links you pass it to the function and get the result out of it, it works if the content-length is being specified in the header of the reponse which is set in most of the cases

Comment: Well I need to pass the function an array full of links and have the size of each link returned back.

Comment: Well Its not working for me, could you detail to me how I pass an array to the function ?