# Get remote file size from HTTPS url

Tags: php, curl

Till now i used the following function to get filesize of files from url.It works perfectly fine if the url is http but fails when its https.Can anyone update it to work with https.

```
<?php
/**
 * Returns the size of a file without downloading it, or -1 if the file
 * size could not be determined.
 *
 * @param $url - The location of the remote file to download. Cannot
 * be null or empty.
 *
 * @return The size of the file referenced by $url, or -1 if the size
 * could not be determined.
 */
function curl_get_file_size( $url ) {
  // Assume failure.
  $result = -1;

  $curl = curl_init( $url );

  // Issue a HEAD request and follow any redirects.
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

  $data = curl_exec( $curl );
  curl_close( $curl );

  if( $data ) {
    $content_length = "unknown";
    $status = "unknown";

    if( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $status = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    if( preg_match( "/Content-Length: (\d+)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
    if( $status == 200 || ($status > 300 && $status <= 308) ) {
      $result = $content_length;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
?>
```

This is not my code btw and the full credit goes to **NebuSoft**
Source: 
[PHP: Remote file size without downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)

Regards

Comment: Add this curl option: `curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to add the below `cURL` parameter to your existing set.

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

- Adding this will stop `cURL` from verifying the peer's certificate.

Answer (score 1):

In this, you have not used curl host verify'r, you have to set this for the communication verify purpose.

Just add this to your parameters

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `strlen(file_get_contents($url));` this will get the length of content through this

Comment: Server may use gzip and then content length won't be accurate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
<?php
$remoteFile = $url;//remote url
$ch = curl_init($remoteFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //not necessary unless the file redirects (like the PHP example we're using here)
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($data === false) {
  echo 'cURL failed';
  exit;
}

$contentLength = 'unknown';
$status = 'unknown';
if (preg_match('/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $status = (int)$matches[1];
}
if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];
}

echo 'HTTP Status: ' . $status . "\n";
echo 'Content-Length: ' . $contentLength;
?>
```

**Refer:** https://www.php.net/filesize

Answer (score 0):

```
function remotefileSize($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $filesize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($filesize) return $filesize;
}
echo remotefileSize('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
//Output
//19978 bytes
```