# Using file_get_contents vs curl for file size

Tags: php, performance, curl, file-upload

I have a file uploading script running on my server which also features remote uploads.. Everything works fine but I am wondering what is the best way to upload via URL. Right now I am using `fopen` to get the file from the remote url pasted in the text box named "from". I have heard that fopen isn't the best way to do it. Why is that?

Also I am using file_get_contents to get the file size of the file from the URL. I have heard that `curl` is better on that part. Why is that and also how can I apply these changes to this script?

```
<?php
$from = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['from']));

if ($from != "") {
    $file = file_get_contents($from);
    $filesize = strlen($file);

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $move = "./uploads/" . $rand2;
        move_upload($_FILES['from']['tmp_name'], $move);

        $newfile = fopen("./uploads/" . $rand2, "wb");
        file_put_contents($newfile, $file);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what `$from` is? Is it like `http://example.com/some/file.jpg`

Comment: Yes... from is basically a text box named "from" and the date would be something like http://example.com/some/file.jpg

Comment: You don't need  to use `feof` or `move_upload` `file_put_contents` writes the whole file in one go. See my updated answer.

Comment: If you have updated your code, please update your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`filesize`](http://php.net/filesize) to get the file size of a file on disk.

`file_get_contents` actually gets the file into memory so `$filesize = strlen(file_get_contents($from));` already gets the file, you just don't do anything with it other than find it size.  You can substitute for you `fwrite` call `file_put_contents`;

See: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) .

`curl` is used when you need more access to the `HTTP` protocol. There are many questions and examples on StackOverflow using `curl` in PHP.

So we can first download the file, in this example I wll use `file_get_contents`, get its size, then put the file in the directory on your local disk.

```
$tmpFile = file_get_contents($from);
$fileSize = strlen($tmpFile);
// you could do a check for file size here
$newFileName = "./uploads/$rand2";
file_put_contents($newFileName, $tmpFile);
```

In your code you have  `move_upload($_FILES['from']['tmp_name'], $move);` but `$_FILES` is only applicable when you have a `<input type="file">` element, which it doesn't seem you have.

P.S. You should probably white-list characters that you allow in a filename for instance  `$goodFilename = preg_replace("/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", "-", $filename)` This is often easier to read and safer.

Replace:

```
while (!feof($file)) {
    $move = "./uploads/" . $rand2;
    move_upload($_FILES['from']['tmp_name'], $move);

    $newfile = fopen("./uploads/" . $rand2, "wb");
    file_put_contents($newfile, $file);
}
```

With:

```
$newFile = "./uploads/" . $rand2;
file_put_contents($newfile, $file);
```

The whole file is read in by `file_get_contents` the whole file is written by `file_put_contents`

Comment: Also what do you mean by "You can substitute for you fwrite call file_put_contents;" How do I get the file size than? Can you please show me the edited code?

Comment: @imbondbaby from your comment above, you would have to run `file_get_contents` to get the full file and then you can check its size. I will update my answer.

Comment: You can remove `&& ($file = file_get_contents($from, "rb")` if you wish to do that check do inside the `if (($from != "")` now replace `$move = ...` to the end of the `while` loop with my code.

Comment: I have done that now... and I get this error Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Comment: Ah, it works fine now after removing the while loop... Why did we have to remove the while loop? Will that effect my uploading script at all?

Comment: Also it is till giving a warning saying Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, on the file_put_contents($newfile, $file); line

Comment: sorry there was typo it should be `$newFile = "./uploads/" . $rand2;`

Comment: That's how I had it originally.. warning still coming

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand your question: You want to get the filesize of a remote fiel given by a URL, and you're not sure which solution ist best/fastest.

At first, the biggest difference between `CURL`, `file_get_contents()` and `fread()` in this context is that CURL and file_get_contents() put the whole thing into memory, while fopen() gives you more control over what parts of the file you want to read. I think fopen() and file_get_contents() are nearly equivalent in your case, because you're dealing with small files and you actually want to get the whole file. So it doesn't make any difference in terms of memory usage.

CURL is just the big brother of file_get_contents(). It is actually a complete HTTP-Client rather than some kind of a wrapper for simple functions.

And talking about HTTP: Don't forget there's more to HTTP than GET and POST. Why don't you just use the resource's meta-data to check it's size **before** you even get it? That's one thing the HTTP method HEAD is meant for. PHP even comes with a built in function for getting the headers: [get_headers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php). It has some flaws though: It still sends a GET request, which makes it probably a little slower, and it follows redirects, which may cause security issues. But you can fix this pretty easily by adjusting the default context:

```
$opts = array(
    'http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'HEAD',
            'max_redirects'=> 1,
            'ignore_errors'=> true
        )
);

stream_context_set_default($opts);
```

Done. Now you can simply get the headers:

```
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com/pic.png', 1);

//set the keys to lowercase so we don't have to deal with lower- and upper case
$lowerCaseHeaders = array_change_key_case($headers);

// 'content-length' is the header we're interested in:
$filesize = $lowerCaseHeaders['content-length'];
```

**NOTE:** `filesize()` will **not** work on a http / https stream wrapper, because stat() is not supported (http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).

And that's pretty much it. Of course you can [achieve the same with CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file) just as easy if you like it better. The approach would be same (reding the headers).

And here's how you get the file and it's size (after downloading) with CURL:

```
// Create a CURL handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Set all the options on this handle
// find a full list on 
// http://au2.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php
// http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php (for actual usage)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/pic.png');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Send the request and store what is returned to a variable
// This actually contains the raw image data now, you could
// pass it to e.g. file_put_contents();
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// get the required info about the request
// find a full list on
// http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php
$filesize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);

// close the handle after you're done
curl_close($ch);
```

Pure PHP approach: http://codepad.viper-7.com/p8mlOt

Using CURL: http://codepad.viper-7.com/uWmsYB

For a nicely formatted and human readable output of the file size I've learned this amazing function from Laravel:

```
function get_file_size($size)
{
  $units = array('Bytes', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB', 'EiB');
  return @round($size / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2).' '.$units[$i];
}
```

If you don't want to deal with all this, you should check out [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's a very powerful and extremely easy to use library for any kind HTTP stuff.

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot understand the differences... but if I want to implement CURL into my code how do I do it? I understand that you said for the file size I can just use curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
But what about actually getting the file?

Comment: @imbondbaby There are actually tons of tutorials about CURL and PHP out there. I've edited my answer with a very basic solution. For more details just google for some tutorials or read the documentation: http://au2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php