# Pushing video to YouTube from S3 account successful but video is "processing" forever

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3, youtube-api

We have the following function running on a WordPress site that accesses an Amazon S3 (public) bucket and attempts to push the video over to YouTube for processing and taking some postmeta with it for title, description, tags, etc.

This script appears to work great except for the actual video upload.  We get the video object created on YouTube with the correct title, description, privacy and tags but the video itself just absolutely refuses to process and YouTube reports processing forever.

Below is the relevant code chunk for uploading:

```
try {
    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();

    if ( ! empty( $args['title'] ) )
        $snippet->setTitle( $args['title'] );

    if ( ! empty( $args['description'] ) )
        $snippet->setDescription( $args['description'] );

    // if ( ! empty( $args['tags'] ) )
    //  $snippet->setTags( $args['tags'] );

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    $snippet->setCategoryId("28");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "private";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 50 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $ytclient->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $ytclient,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $videoFileSize = filesize($videoPath);
    $media->setFileSize( $videoFileSize );
```

What could be causing the failure?

Comment: Is the video long? Like 1-2 hours with music? I sometimes find when I manually upload or process of a live recording with music will take sometimes upto 10 hours because I can only assume youtube wants do a content match ID check on it.

Comment: The videos are long (5-10 minutes) but there's nothing in there that would trigger a content match issue. Additionally, we have had them sitting in the "stuck" state for 3 to 4 days before we give up and delete it.

Comment: have you tried checking the `$status` after `while()` as written [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload) ?

Comment: @TechnoKnol Yep, we had it in there, took it out.  Makes no difference either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending the content length and youtube is sitting there waiting for "more" content.

Looking at your code you are using resume-able uploads.

**Updated with more info:**

From your code

```
$videoFileSize = filesize($videoPath);
```

where

```
$videoPath = $s3dir . $args['file_path'];
```

and

```
$s3dir is "s3://coughvideo/"
```

Therefore when you do the setFileSize here:

```
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $ytclient,
    $insertRequest,
    'video/*',
    null,
    true,
    $chunkSizeBytes
);
$videoFileSize = filesize($videoPath);
$media->setFileSize( $videoFileSize );
```

Quite sure filesize will only work with local files, so you wont be able to get the filesize for a remote URL.

You are going to have either

- Request the filesize from Amazon first and use that
- Download it locally so you can figure out the filesize (not sure if you want to do that).
- Use CURL either example below (not sure if an option on your S3 instance - depending on your security).

[PHP: Remote file size without downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)

**Edit:**

Switching the "bad" code above to:

```
$head = get_headers($videoPath,1); // get the header array from Amazon S3
$videoSize = $head['Content-Length']; // Get Mr. FileSize
$media->setFileSize($videoSize); // Set Mr. FileSize
```

This works to get the filesize in place.

Comment: We're following the script from YouTube for v3 of the API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert and we're not able to get the above to work properly...

Comment: To clarify, this may indeed be the answer but we're struggling with how to pass content-length properly.

Comment: Echo $videoFileSize to the browser just after you set it, what value do you get and make sure it is correct for the filesize.

Comment: This code "$videoFileSize = filesize($videoPath);"

Quite sure filesize will only work with local files, so you wont be able to get the filesize for a remote URL. You are going to have to request the filesize from Amazon first and use that or download it locally so you can figure out the filesize (not sure if you want to do that).

Comment: So that's definitely ONE of the problems. I've placed the code used to work around it in your answer. Turns out our testing box had stat configured and that allowed filesize() to function remotely.  The bad news is we are still getting errors but now the errors are different.  I'm probably going to have to edit the question and reduce its scope to fit your answer and then move into a new direction.

Comment: No problems, glad to help, your edit looks like a good solution to get the size.