# Download external file with PHP fopen and/or cURL

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, download, fopen

I can't get my download script to work with external files, the file will download but is corrupted/not working. I think it's because I can't get the filesize of the external file with filesize() function.

This is my script:

```
function getMimeType($filename){
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);

    $mime_types=array(
        "pdf" => "application/pdf",
        "txt" => "text/plain",
        "html" => "text/html",
        "htm" => "text/html",
        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
        "zip" => "application/zip",
        "doc" => "application/msword",
        "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
        "png" => "image/png",
        "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
        "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
        "php" => "text/plain",
        "csv" => "text/csv",
        "xlsx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        "pptx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
        "docx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    );

    if(isset($mime_types[$ext])){
        return $mime_types[$ext];
    } else {
        return 'application/octet-stream';
    }
}

$path = "http://www.example.com/file.zip";

/* Does not work on external files
// check file is readable or not exists
if (!is_readable($path))
    die('File is not readable or does not exists!');
*/

$file_headers = @get_headers($path);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    echo "Files does not exist.";
} else {

$filename = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

// get mime type of file by extension
$mime_type = getMimeType($filename);

// set headers
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: -1');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");

// read file as chunk
if ( $fp = fopen($path, 'rb') ) {
    ob_end_clean();

    while( !feof($fp) and (connection_status()==0) ) {
        print(fread($fp, 8192));
        flush();
    }

    @fclose($fp);
    exit;
}

}
```

I believe it can be done with cURL - but my knowledge is lacking. 
What I would like to know:

- How do I check if the file exist and how do I get the filesize with cURL?
- Would it be better just to use cURL and forget about fopen?
- Is the headers set correctly?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you leave off the Content-Length: header.  Can you download the whole file before you output it?

Comment: Please provide some output from an attempt to debug the problem.

Comment: The ANSWER is YES, forget about `fopen` and use `curl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this process as well, I am assuming that your source url is `$sourceUrl` and destination/ path to save file is `$destinationPath`

```
$destFilename = 'my_file_name.ext';
$destinationPath = 'your/destination/path/'.$destFilename;

if(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {                                
    if( ! @file_put_contents($destinationPath, file_get_contents($sourceUrl))){
        $http_status = $http_response_header[0];
        sprintf('%s encountered while attempting to download %s',$http_status, $sourceUrl );
        break;
    }
} elseif(function_exists('curl_init')) {
    $ch = curl_init($sourceUrl);
    $fp = fopen($destinationPath, "wb");

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_FILE => $fp,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120); // in seconds

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    //delete the file if the download was unsuccessful
    if($http_status != 200) {
        unlink($destinationPath);
        sprintf('HTTP status %s encountered while attempting to download %s', $http_status, $sourceUrl );

    }
} else {    
    sprintf('Looks like %s is off and %s is not enabled. No images were imported.', '<code>allow_url_fopen</code>', '<code>cURL</code>'  );
    break;
}
```

You can use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);` in case of curl to get the file info and use it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your content-length that gets set to `0`.
Since you already have the content-length from the `get_headers` call, simply change the following line:

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
```

to:

```
header($file_headers[8]);
```

Note that the content of `$file_headers` might vary (8 worked for me), check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) for details, or execute a `print_r($file_headers)` to see what you get in there.

If you don't care about the content-length header, simply comment it out, most browsers should handle this without any problem.

Comment: You do realize that setting the executing scripts headers has not that much impact over the query he is trying to do to an external url via fopen.

Comment: His code works, there is nothing wrong with using fopen, his only problem comes from the fact that he is passing 0 as the content-length header.

Comment: But my question was about the headers set for what `the current` php script will return (meaning, the use of `header()`) and it's influence over the `query` he was doing with fopen on an external url. I hope I clarified it.

Answer (score 1):

this code is work fine to download from url :

```
set_time_limit(0);

//File to save the contents to
$fp = fopen ('r.jpg', 'w+');

$url = "http://cgr.ir/test.jpg";

//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);

//give curl the file pointer so that it can write to it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);//get curl response

//done
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Returns the size of a file without downloading it, or -1 if the file
 * size could not be determined.
 *
 * @param $url - The location of the remote file to download. Cannot
 * be null or empty.
 *
 * @return The size of the file referenced by $url, or -1 if the size
 * could not be determined.
 */
function curl_get_file_size( $url ) {
  // Assume failure.
  $result = -1;

  $curl = curl_init( $url );

  // Issue a HEAD request and follow any redirects.
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, get_user_agent_string() );

  $data = curl_exec( $curl );
  curl_close( $curl );

  if( $data ) {
    $content_length = "unknown";
    $status = "unknown";

    if( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $status = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    if( preg_match( "/Content-Length: (\d+)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
    if( $status == 200 || ($status > 300 && $status <= 308) ) {
      $result = $content_length;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
?>
```

Function call:

```html
$file_size = curl_get_file_size( "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
function get_data($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Unfortunately your lack of detail about your specific query or files rendered me unable to come up with more exact code to match your situation.
And the above (or below) `curl_get_file_size` will help you with the size in case you ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is a good idea not to rely on php curl module availability. Your snippet works with a little modification:

First change

```
$file_headers = @get_headers($path);
```

to

```
$file_headers = @get_headers($path,1);
```

to get named array keys (see [php reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)).

With this modification the http status code still comes in $file_headers[0] but you'll get some more and useful data which can be passed thru (validation recommended): Content-Length and even Content-Type (which allows you waiving your approach of mime-type detection upon file suffix).

Change

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
```

to

```
header("Content-Length: " . $file_headers['Content-Length']);
```

and

```
header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
```

to

```
header("Content-Type: " . $file_headers['Content-Type']);
```

Even if your "path" is a trusted source you might want to add some validation as you should not trust exernal data being of the kind you expect.