# How do I get youtube video direct link file size info using php curl?

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I want to display the size of youtube video size on the direct link. I have a link to an mp4 format file that is 98 MB in size. I want to display the size when you browse this link your will get file.

Direct url link:

```
$url ='https://r4---sn-a8au-p5qs.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=9216B94F5EA16F023DE3D34C6881F8AFA20E1EBA.4B56920C4B2BAB848AC847E0EB4C1E01FB01685C&itag=22&ratebypass=yes&expire=1424904527&id=o-AA8OyXA6gxAGHzkwqf94rIO0LTrhD8iHuUc9lMI9ED76&pl=46&fexp=905657%2C907263%2C916942%2C923382%2C927622%2C934601%2C934954%2C9406984%2C943917%2C947225%2C947240%2C947601%2C948124%2C951703%2C952302%2C952605%2C952612%2C952901%2C955301%2C957201%2C959701&mm=31&ipbits=0&dur=1366.192&mt=1424882845&ms=au&key=yt5&upn=SIiUMnjm5o0&source=youtube&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mv=m&initcwndbps=1567500&ip=2001%3A4802%3A7805%3A101%3Abe76%3A4eff%3Afe20%3A31e4&sver=3&requiressl=yes&title=PHP%3A+Create+Your+Own+MVC+%28Part+1%29';
```

php curl code I am using to get code

```
function retrieve_remote_file_size($url){
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

     curl_close($ch);
     return $size;
}
```

It is giving me 1419. How do I get the correct file size?

Answer (score 0):

getID3 supports video formats. See: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
 $file = $getID3->analyze($filename);
 echo("Filesize: ".$file['filesize']." bytes<br />");
```

Note: You must include the getID3 classes before this will work! See the above link.

If you have the ability to modify the PHP installation on your server, a PHP extension for this purpose is ffmpeg-php. See: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

edit:

Found something about this here:

Here's the best way (that I've found) to get the size of a remote file. Note that HEAD requests don't get the actual body of the request, they just retrieve the headers. So making a HEAD request to a resource that is 100MB will take the same amount of time as a HEAD request to a resource that is 1KB.

```
  $curl = curl_init( $url );

  // Issue a HEAD request and follow any redirects.
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, get_user_agent_string() );

  $data = curl_exec( $curl );
  curl_close( $curl );

  if( $data ) {
    $content_length = "unknown";
    $status = "unknown";

    if( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $status = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    if( preg_match( "/Content-Length: (\d+)/", $data, $matches ) ) {
      $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
    }

    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
    if( $status == 200 || ($status > 300 && $status <= 308) ) {
      $result = $content_length;
    }
  }

   return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

Usage:

```
$file_size = curl_get_file_size(   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file" );
```

Comment: Please use youtube video direct link url which was post by me in this post, and then tell me if it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

The 1491 bytes you get is the length of the redirect. Add the following curl option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, True);
```

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php) it should be true by default, but it wasn't for me.