# Why can't get the length of the iso file with `CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD` in php_curl?

Tags: php, curl

I want to get the length of the iso file on the web

http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.0.0/i386/iso-cd/debian-8.0.0-i386-lxde-CD-1.iso

```
<?php
    $szUrl = 'http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.0.0/i386/iso-cd/debian-8.0.0-i386-lxde-CD-1.iso';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $szUrl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    echo $size;
?>
```

The output is -1 with the code,How to get the length of the iso file properly with php_curl?
With the answer of Leggendario , the key of my problem is to set 
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to get right answer.
It makes my question different from the `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)

> **CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD**
>
> Pass a pointer to a double to receive the content-length of the
>   download. This is the value read from the Content-Length: field. Since
>   7.19.4, this returns -1 if the size isn't known.

You must first execute curl:

```
curl_exec($curl);

$size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
echo $size;

curl_close($curl);
```

But be careful because *http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.0.0/i386/iso-cd/debian-8.0.0-i386-lxde-CD-1.iso* is just a redirection to *http://gensho.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/8.0.0/i386/iso-cd/debian-8.0.0-i386-lxde-CD-1.iso*. You may want set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to true.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Otherwise you will get the size of the page of the redirect.