# get file size from a url possibly have redirects

Tags: php, filesize

I have tried many things including this but i can't figure out why i'm not getting it's file size.

```
echo remotefileSize("http://iristech.co/download/277/");

function remotefileSize($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $filesize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($filesize) return $filesize;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file

Comment: Sorry already tried like 10 answers from SO.

Comment: What about using that function I've sent in previous comment? It has 56 up-votes so I guess it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah i have tried it, its returning -1, you can also try it with the url i have mentioned in question.

Comment: Ok, but did you check -why- it is returning "-1"? Is the status not 200? Is $data empty? ...

Comment: it works on localhost but not on godaddy(i'm already regretting)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of Iris. The software from the link you use.
It doesn't work, because this is not a link to a file. It's link to a script, which links to a file. Try with different file or upload the file on your hosting :)