# PHP, Determinate size of remote file

Tags: php

I'm creating an importer of products in woocommerce from an xml file .
The process fails because there are empty photos that have no weight .

How can I determinate the size (bytes) of a remote file in php  ?

THanks
Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Remote file size without downloading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)

Comment: What you have tried to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
getimagesize("http://www.example.com/gifs/logo.gif");
```