# How to find the download size of a file?

Tags: php, file, download, limit

I am facing a problem in one of my website.I have applied download data limit check and user have the option to download files in his/her profile.My question is:

> How to find the download size of a file? So, I have applied the
>   appropriate limit checks.

Comment: You need to find file size?

Comment: what is download size?

Comment: Yes i need the downloaded file size,so on the basis of that value, i calculate the used space limit and the apply related checks.

Comment: Your question doesn't make it any sense.

Comment: Please refer old post :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PHP's [filesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function:

```
$size = filesize('/path/to/file');
```

This will return the size of the file in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Returns the size of the file in bytes, or FALSE (and generates an error of level E_WARNING) in case of an error.

**Note:** Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.

```
<?php

// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt: 1024 bytes

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
echo $filename . ': ' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes';

?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php