# Prevent loading from remote source if file is larger than a given size

Tags: php, domdocument, filesize

Let's say I want XML Files only with upto 10MB to be loaded from a  remote server.

Something like

```
$xml_file = "http://example.com/largeXML.xml";// size= 500MB

//PRACTICAL EXAMPLE: $xml_file = "http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/pir/psd7003.xml";// size= 683MB

 /*GOAL: Do anything that can be done to hinder this large file from being loaded by the DOMDocument without having to load the File n check*/

$dom =  new DOMDocument();

$dom->load($xml_file /*LOAD only IF the file_size is <= 10MB....else...echo 'File is too large'*/);
```

How can this *possibly* be achieved?.... Any idea or alternative? or best approach to achieving this would be highly appreciated.

I checked [PHP: Remote file size without downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file) but when I try with something like

```
var_dump(
    curl_get_file_size(
        "http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhainaut/"
    )
);
```

I get `string 'unknown' (length=7)`

When I try with `get_headers` as suggested below, the Content-Length is missing in the headers, so this will not work reliably either.

Please kindly advise how to determine the `length` and avoid sending it to the `DOMDocument` if it exceeds `10MB`

Comment: Did you look at [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function?

Comment: @MawiaHL Can you try: `var_dump(filesize("http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/pir/psd7003.xml"))`

Comment: Page not found is the result.

Comment: @MawiaHL -- This loads in the browser: https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xsl-20011015/xslspec.xml .... but doesn't work with `filesize()`..... in `var_dump(filesize('https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xsl-20011015/xslspec.xml'))`

Comment: @DownVoters.... Please advise what is wrong with the Question. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally working. The headers solution was obviously not going to work broadly.  In this solution, we open a file handle and read the XML line by line until it hits the threshold of $max_B. If the file is too big, we still have the overhead of reading it up until the 10MB mark, but it's working as expected. If the file is less than $max_B, it proceeds...

```
$xml_file = "http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhainaut/";
//$xml_file = "http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/pir/psd7003.xml";

$fh = fopen($xml_file, "r");  

if($fh){
    $file_string = '';
    $total_B = 0;
    $max_B = 10485760;
    //run through lines of the file, concatenating them into a string
    while (!feof($fh)){
        if($line = fgets($fh)){
            $total_B += strlen($line);
            if($total_B < $max_B){
                $file_string .= $line;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

    if($total_B < $max_B){
        echo 'File ok. Total size = '.$total_B.' bytes. Proceeding...';
        //proceed
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($file_string); //NOTE the method change because we're loading from a string   

    } else {
        //reject
        echo 'File too big! Max size = '.$max_B.' bytes.';  
    }

    fclose($fh);

} else {
    echo '404 file not found!';
}
```

Comment: This Crashes when tested with: `file_get_contents("http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/pir/psd7003.xml"); size //683MB ` ... Kindly advise

Comment: Script Hanged had to restart the server... `file_get_contents` tries to load the entire `683 MB` into memory before its worked on

Comment: Yeah, we're banging up against the maximum size for a single variable it's the `memory_limit` setting in php.ini.  We need a better solution - one that can test the file without loading the whole thing.

Comment: Nice try!.. however, these files are random from random servers. ...This fails on something like:  ` $xml_file = "http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhaina‌​ut/";`

`$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($xml_file, TRUE));` The `headers` do not include `Content-Length`.... please see **@Mawia HL** 's answer... Thanks at least for trying.. :)

Comment: Ok, I've added some simple error handling. You can update precisely how errors are handled as you like. But this does answer the question - if the file exists, and it's too big, you can now determine that without downloading it.

Comment: ___That's really great!.... I'll give it a thought. Though just wondering for `dailymotion.com` **users** intending to load their `xml` contents will always get the `ERROR`.... .... for a LINK  like: `dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhaina‌ut/`  ... shows the `XML` in the `Webrowser` but the `headers` don't include `'Content-length'` ... but thanks alot

Comment: `get_headers()` does a full GET request, so you need to provide a stream context and change the method to HEAD to prevent downloading the thing just to get it's size. See example #2 in the PHP manual.

Comment: Ok, finally working for daily motion, and also rejecting the oversize files. Check it out.

Comment: @larsAnders .... So far your suggestion has worked perfectly with multiple tests. You deserve **"Un Coup the Chapeau"** un-less a different solution is suggested... but this works very-well... Merci Beaucoup!

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the challenge - for sure the most interesting question of the day.

Comment: @larsAnders you're awesome buddy... if you like the question, please upVote it. Thax again!

Comment: I would *still* check whether the headers are there, because if they are, it'll save us the trouble of potentially downloading 10MB of garbage to decide that it's garbage.

Answer (score 1):

10MB is equal to 10485760 B. If content-length is not specified, it will use curl which is available since php5. I got this source from somewhere in SO but could not remember it.:

```
function get_filesize($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
    if (isset($headers['Content-Length'])) return $headers['Content-Length'];
    if (isset($headers['Content-length'])) return $headers['Content-length'];
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($c, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 
         (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) 
          Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'),
        ));
    curl_exec($c);
    return curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
    }
}
    $filesize = get_filesize("http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhainaut/");
    if($filesize<=10485760){
        echo 'Fine';
    }else{
       echo $filesize.'File is too big';
    }
```

.

[Check demo here](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/6cpm-kwif)

Comment: @Mawai HL--- We have tried that before it fails when used on this XML: `$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers("http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhainaut/", TRUE));` The headers do not include `Content-Length`.... please try n advise. Thx

Comment: @ErickBest, http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhaina‌​ut/ does not return anything. It only returns `Page not found The page you're looking for is either restricted or doesn't exist`. So how can anyone know the size of the file when it does not exist at all.

Comment: --Please try this in the Web-Browser: http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhainaut/

Comment: If there is no content at all, get_headers won't return anything.

Comment: Sure... makes sense. but when run in the browser the XML shows up... if it is larger than  `10MB` it should not be loaded to the `DOMDocument`

Comment: `get_headers()` does a full GET request, so you need to provide a stream context and change the method to HEAD to prevent downloading the thing just to get it's size. See example #2 in the PHP manual.

Comment: @Mawia HL ... Yes... **Confirmed** ..., Working perfectly ... _(Wish I could have 2 Accepted Answers)_

Comment: @Mawia HL The `code` in the demo works with multiple tests... but not the ones in your answer. Can you past the `demo codes` as your answer?

Comment: @ErickBest, The advantage of using my answer over the accepted is that some host providers disabled fopen() function. On a Windows webserver, when using fopen with a file path stored in a variable, PHP will return an error if the variable isn't encoded in ASCII. When using SSL, Microsoft IIS will violate the protocol by closing the connection without sending a close_notify indicator. So Curl is better.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: New Answer a bit workaroundish:
You can't check the Dom Elements Length, BUT, you can make a header request and get the filesize from the URL:

```
<?php

function i_hope_this_works( $XmlUrl ) {
    //lets assume we fk up so we set size to -1  
    $size = -1;

      $request = curl_init( $XmlUrl );

      // Go for a head request, so the body of a 1 gb file will take the same as 1 kb
      curl_setopt( $request, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
      curl_setopt( $request, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
      curl_setopt( $request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
      curl_setopt( $request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
      curl_setopt( $request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, get_user_agent_string() );

      $requesteddata = curl_exec( $request );
      curl_close( $request );

      if( $requesteddata ) {
        $content_length = "unknown";
        $status = "unknown";

        if( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/", $requesteddata, $matches ) ) {
          $status = (int)$matches[1];
        }

        if( preg_match( "/Content-Length: (\d+)/", $requesteddata, $matches ) ) {
          $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
        }

        // you can google status qoutes 200 is Ok for example
        if( $status == 200 || ($status > 300 && $status <= 308) ) {
          $result = $content_length;
        }
      }

      return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

You should now be able to get every Filesize you want by URL just with

```
$file_size = i_hope_this_works('yourURLasString')
```

Comment: RESULT: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'size' in C:\.....\fileSize_tst\index.php on line 5`

Comment: What is the value of size ?

Comment: The Size is unknown....can be anything size.... but must not be `> 10MB`... the File comes from a remote server..(Please read the question ones more)

Comment: I mean what is in the variable size

Comment: @johannes-- you added the variable `size` in your answer and I said that there is no way the variable `size` can be used bcz the file is loaded from a remoteServer with unknown `size`....

Comment: Actually size will be generated from PHP, for you, but i don't know if it works with a remote server since I don't use it alot, i will edit my answer to have more specific Code ... That at least works for me

Comment: @johannes--  The file is not being `uploaded` it is already uploaded somewhere in a different server, we simply want to read it using the `DOMDocument` but we want to **STOP reading** ...or ...**NOT-READ at all** if its size exceeds `10MB`... i.e: FILES LIKE: `http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/pir/psd7003.xml` ......or..... `http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/SwissProt/SwissProt.xml` are just too large

Comment: Try int filesize ( string $filename ) filename is the path to the file, from which Server are you getting the files?

Comment: __From Multiple Servers... The Servers are extremely random. but the Main GOAL is we do whatever we can so that `NO FILE` with `size` beyond `10MB` should be passed to the `DOMDocument`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109773/discussion-between-johannes-geidel-and-erickbest).

Comment: This approach failed ... returns `unknown`... when tested with `http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/user/dialhainaut/`