# get remote file size in php in KB / MB / GB format

Tags: javascript, php, curl

i've using this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file) for getting remote file size 
but i am getting sizes in bites i want to show that in Kb,Mb or in Gb

Comment: Please add your code so that others could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your bytes value into kb/mb/gb

> 1 byte = 0.001 KB
>
> 1 kb = 0.001 MB

likewise.

Comment: In some situations, you might want to divide bytes by 1024 instead of 1000 to get kilobytes, and again by 1024 to get megabytes.

Answer (score -1):

Well the easiest way is just get the result and divide it by 1024 for K, 1024 again for Meg, and 1024 again for Gig?

So 
    $bytes = curl_get_file_size( $url );
Then
 
    $kbytes = $bytes / 1024;
    $mbytes = $kbytes / 1024;
    $gbytes = $mbytes / 1024;