# Laravel API temp image via url

Tags: laravel, filesystems, temp

I'm working on a Laravel API project, let see when you upload a image I change the colors, with a shell script. The api accepts urls so that means I have to save the image in a temp folder so that I can edit it and save it to my S3 filesystem. Is it convenient that I save the temp image in the S3 filesystems or local?

Comment: Maybe try rephrasing your question.  I'm having difficulty understanding what you're trying to do and what you're asking.

Comment: @wheelmaker Sorry, I changed it. hope you understand it now.

Comment: How are you uploading the image?  If it's through a form on the front end, isn't it already stored in a local temp file for you?  Can you not work with it from there and then upload to S3 after you're done?

Comment: @wheelmaker The image was sent via a url in the API request like this `" url ":" https://vanijzendoorn.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/new-google-logo-png.png "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will likely be much faster to save the image locally in a temp directory to make the changes before storing it on S3.  You can use `sys_get_temp_dir()` to get a path used for temporary files.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php

Comment: Is there a way you can get the file size from url without putting it on the temp folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/remote-file-size-without-downloading-file